# Sitecore MVC endless loop for controller call

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I added a Controller rendering inside of Sitecore, created a basic controller at my solution, added simple view.

Set up a design layout to use my Controller rendering.
And i see that Sitecore make a call to my controller but it is going to endless loop. What is wrong ?

```cs
public class MyController : GlassController
{
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen similar issue once. From what I remember the answer was to return `PartialView` instead of `View` and specify the path to the view in the method, e.g.:

```cs
return PartialView("/views/MyView.cshtml");
```

Comment: Yes I was also close to try partial view. I suggest that this is some kind of Sitecore issue. Be course all examples are working fine with normal view. For me it is not useful to write path manually. What do you think Marek? or may be it is just some specific setting in sitecore.

Comment: I've never had this issue while using `View`, but I've seen that someone had this problem in the past. TBH I do like having view path specified manually - it's easier to navigate to the view in Visual Studio with Resharper. But I get your point and I agree - it should happen automatically as well.